# Transform http service response in Angular using rxjs

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

Here is use case :

- I am calling one http method which returns me ID.
- Passing above ID to get Array of object response.

response :

```
[
   {
      "cuisp":"17296744",
      "instr_type":"Common Stock (CS)",
      "isConversion":"No",
      "issue_date":"04/31/2020",
      "rev_rule":"common equity tier 1",
      "isCumulative":"Noncumulative",
      "notional_amt":"8434.695",
      "amt_transacted":"8434.695",
      "isPerpetual":"Perpetual",
      "isFixed":"Floating"
   }, ...
]
```

Now I want to add `isEditable : false` to every object inside that response.
I tried below code.

```
this._httpservice.getTemplateForVersion(this.selected_template).pipe(
      concatMap((res: any) => {
        return this._httpservice.getTemplateJsonData(res.id).pipe(
          mergeAll(),
          map((d: any) => {
            d['isEditable'] = false;
            return d;
          })
        );
      })
    ).subscribe(res => {
      console.log(res);
    })
```

however its just updating first element of response.
I need final response to be

```
[
       {
          "cuisp":"17296744",
          "instr_type":"Common Stock (CS)",
          "isConversion":"No",
          "issue_date":"04/31/2020",
          "rev_rule":"common equity tier 1",
          "isCumulative":"Noncumulative",
          "notional_amt":"8434.695",
          "amt_transacted":"8434.695",
          "isPerpetual":"Perpetual",
          "isFixed":"Floating",
          "isEditable":false,
       }, ...
    ]
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe: `return { ...d, isEditable: false};`?

Comment: this is same as what I did ...

Comment: *this is same as what I did* ? What does that mean?

Comment: `d['isEditable'] = false;return d;` this is same as above spread.. tried by ur suggestion as well .. no luck

Comment: It may not fix your problem, but may be easier to understand what's going on, if you replace mergeAll() and map() with mergeMap()

Comment: What are you merging with your mergeAll() call? HTTP services generally don't return higher-order streams.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RxJs **map** operator lets you modify the stream, but modification itself should be done inside the function:

```
map((d: any) => {
    return d.map(item => ({...item, isEditable: false}));        
})
```

Comment: This is correct.  @user1608841, you don't need `mergeAll()` operator.  Simply use `concatMap()` followed by `map()`.  Actually I think `switchMap` is more appropriate, but it probably doesn't matter because http calls only emit once anyway.

So, altogether: `this._httpservice.getTemplateForVersion(this.selected_template).pipe(
    switchMap(res => this._httpservice.getTemplateJsonData(res.id)),
    map((d:any[]) => d.map(item => {...item, isEditable: false}))
).subscribe(res => {
    console.log(res);
})`